# What happens to a node/menu item once it's been deleted?

Tags: nodes, routes

Once a node or menu item etc has been deleted, is there a way to restore it? Other than restoring the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you delete a node or a menu item you cannot restore it unless reverting the DB.

You can use revisions and published status in order to emulate the node deletion or you can try modules like [Recover](http://drupal.org/project/recover).

Comment: Thanks @FiNeX

I just tried using it but cannot work it out. There is no readme file or any documentation online :(